# Using Pandas to drop duplicates and match row elements of 2 csv files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, compare, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to compare two csv files. One csv file has extra (unique) entries. I want to match the CSV video IDs exactly on both csv files. Is there any function/way to set to CSV files to one another and delete the rows of the CSV file with extra entries till identical to the other CSV?

```
import pandas as pd 

import numpy as np

#What I have so far, need to compare a df1 with df2

df2 = pd.read_excel('CompareTo.xlsx")
df = pd.read_excel('ChTest.xlsx')

df = df.sort_values(by = ['videoID'] , ascending = True)

df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='videoID', keep="first")

print(df)

df = df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\alant\Desktop\ChTest.xlsx', index = None, header=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find video ids that are common to both:

```
new_df = pd.merge(df, df2, how='inner', on=['videoID'])
```